# nginx throws temporary 404 errors on vue-router URLs

Tags: nginx, vue-router

I have a Vue/vue-router app that uses Google Authentication. It uses HTML5 history mode. I configured nginx with [the try_files line recommended in the vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html). Immediately after deployment, the route '/' works, but after authentication, the redirect to, say, '/profile/games?token=XYZ' hits a generic nginx 404 page. If I let the server simmer for a day, I am able to access all routes with no 404s. The second I deploy a new version of my Vue app, though, the 404s return. What nginx config am I missing? This is my config as it stands:

```
upstream dev_diplio_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:9001;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name dev.dipl.io;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name dev.dipl.io;
    root                    [root to directory goes here];
    index                   index.html;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # SSL config goes here. Omitted for various reasons.
}
```

Comment: I have similar question, have you found any solutions?